# Square brackets and dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Okay I am rather puzzled by the different behaviours of dataframes and xtses in R and I'm hoping someone can explain it to me.

```
df = as.data.frame(x = c(1,2),row.names = c("2012-12-12","2012-12-13"))
xts = as.xts(x=c(1,2),order.by = as.POSIXct(c("2012-12-12","2012-12-13")))
```

I have two different datasets here. When you print them, they look almost similar. When I want the first row of the xts, `xts[1,]` returns the row with colnames and the index. But when you do `df[1,]` it only returns a vector.

Is there a way to return the first row of the dataframe, complete with the rownames and colname? I'm aware that I can hack it by doing `as.data.frame(as.xts(df)[1,])` but is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very particular case where a subsetting operation by rows on a data frame has only ONE cell.

In that case, you need to specify `drop = FALSE`, here

```
df[1, , drop = FALSE]
```

I'd add a recommendation that when you create a data frame from scratch, use the `data.frame()` function instead of `as.data.frame()`

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome! It's not obvious, though, because usually the dimensions don't get dropped when you subset by rows. If this was helpful, please upvote it! If it answered your question, please mark it as the answer! - says the thirsty stackoverflow user